# expo-modules-core:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]

Tags: expo

Getting this error when I try to build my expo bareflow app

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.

[CXX1429] error when building with cmake using C:\Users\MASHEE\Documents\expo projects\zeropen-app\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android\CMakeLists.txt: C++ build system [configure] failed while executing:
@echo off
"C:\Users\MASHEE\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.22.1\bin\cmake.exe" ^
"-HC:\Users\MASHEE\Documents\expo projects\zeropen-app\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android" ^
"-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android" ^
"-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON" ^
"-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=21" ^
"-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21" ^
"-DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a" ^
"-DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a" ^
"-DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\MASHEE\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\23.1.7779620" ^
"-DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\MASHEE\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\23.1.7779620" ^
"-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\MASHEE\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\23.1.7779620\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake" ^
"-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\MASHEE\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.22.1\bin\ninja.exe" ^
"-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\MASHEE\Documents\expo projects\zeropen-app\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\5n3y3z5z\obj\arm64-v8a" ^
"-DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\MASHEE\Documents\expo projects\zeropen-app\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\5n3y3z5z\obj\arm64-v8a" ^
"-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" ^
"-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=C:\Users\MASHEE\Documents\expo projects\zeropen-app\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android\.cxx\Debug\5n3y3z5z\prefab\arm64-v8a\prefab" ^
"-BC:\Users\MASHEE\Documents\expo projects\zeropen-app\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android\.cxx\Debug\5n3y3z5z\arm64-v8a" ^
-GNinja ^
"-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared" ^
"-DREACT_NATIVE_DIR=C:\Users\MASHEE\Documents\expo projects\zeropen-app\node_modules\react-native" ^
"-DREACT_NATIVE_SO_DIR=C:\Users\MASHEE\Documents\expo projects\zeropen-app\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android\build/react/jni" ^
"-DREACT_NATIVE_TARGET_VERSION=71" ^
"-DBOOST_VERSION=1_76_0" ^
"-DUSE_HERMES=false" ^
"-DHERMES_HEADER_DIR=null" ^
"-DIS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED=false" ^
"-DPROJECT_BUILD_DIR=C:\Users\MASHEE\Documents\expo projects\zeropen-app\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android\build" ^
"-DREACT_ANDROID_DIR=C:\Users\MASHEE\Documents\expo projects\zeropen-app\node_modules\react-native/ReactAndroid" ^
"-DREACT_ANDROID_BUILD_DIR=C:\Users\MASHEE\Documents\expo projects\zeropen-app\node_modules\react-native/ReactAndroid/build" ^
"-DUNIT_TEST=false"
from C:\Users\MASHEE\Documents\expo projects\zeropen-app\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

Execution optimizations have been disabled for 1 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.
Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.

BUILD FAILED in 48m 44s
484 actionable tasks: 310 executed, 169 from cache, 5 up-to-date
Error: C:\Users\MASHEE\Documents\expo projects\zeropen-app\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: C:\Users\MASHEE\Documents\expo projects\zeropen-app\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\MASHEE\Documents\expo projects\zeropen-app\node_modules\expo\node_modules@expo\cli\node_modules@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:52:23)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
at cp.emit (C:\Users\MASHEE\Documents\expo projects\zeropen-app\node_modules\expo\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
...
at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (C:\Users\MASHEE\Documents\expo projects\zeropen-app\node_modules\expo\node_modules@expo\cli\node_modules@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:17:21)
at spawnGradleAsync (C:\Users\MASHEE\Documents\expo projects\zeropen-app\node_modules\expo\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:72:46)
at Object.assembleAsync (C:\Users\MASHEE\Documents\expo projects\zeropen-app\node_modules\expo\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:52:18)
at runAndroidAsync (C:\Users\MASHEE\Documents\expo projects\zeropen-app\node_modules\expo\node_modules@expo\cli\build\src\run\android\runAndroidAsync.js:31:24)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Managed or bare workflow?
bare

What platform(s) does this occur on?
Android

Package versions
"expo-dev-client": "~2.1.5"

Environment
expo-env-info 1.0.5 environment info:
System:
OS: Windows 10 10.0.19045
Binaries:
Node: 18.15.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
Yarn: 1.22.19 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\yarn.CMD
npm: 9.6.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
IDEs:
Android Studio: AI-221.6008.13.2211.9619390
npmPackages:
expo: ~48.0.6 => 48.0.6
react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
react-native: 0.71.3 => 0.71.3
Expo Workflow: bare

Reproducible demo
npx create-expo-app my-app

npx expo install expo-dev-client

npx expo prebuild --clean

yarn android
```

I tried build my exist app, which I have successfully built before, and now getting the error. I then tried to create a new app using npx create-expo-app my-app. I then ran npx expo install expo-dev-client, npx expo prebuild --clean. Finally ran yarn android but got the same build error on the new app